Subscription count = 0 even though the subscription is created by MSTeams App on behalf of the user for the transcripts resource
Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-callrecording-and-calltranscript we tried creating the subscription for the transcripts available at the tenant-level.
Useful Information:
client_id = '37339a85-7942-4728-b909-953a4b95ec63',
tenant_id = '91e213e9-498d-46b9-bc35-cd0aa9390b45',
MicrosoftAppType=MultiTenant


We have created a graph client with our application credentials as follows:

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
graph_client = GraphServiceClient(
credentials=credentials, scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])


We successully created the subscription as follows: (Subscribed to the transcirpts available at the teanant level.)

request_body = Subscription(
        change_type="created",
        notification_url= "<ngrok_url>/api",
        lifecycle_notification_url= "<ngrok_url>/lifecycleurl",
        resource=f"communications/onlineMeetings/getAllTranscripts",
        include_resource_data = True,
        #expiration_date_time="2024-07-08T18:59:45.9356913Z",
        expiration_date_time=expiration_date_time,
 
        client_state="secretC",
        encryption_certificate = "Valid Open SSl Certificate",
        encryption_certificate_id = "Valid Open SSl Certificate ID",
        )
        result = await graph_client.subscriptions.post(request_body)


This code creates a valid subscription as below:

Subscription(
    additional_data=
    {'@odata.context': '
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity'}
,
    id='2d6b102c-e5e7-43af-b446-5c936b1988e6', odata_type=None, application_id='37339a85-7942-4728-b909-953a4b95ec63', change_type='created', client_state='secretC', 
    creator_id='86c11b9c-b0f1-4d07-816e-c6e8bd03b200', 
    encryption_certificate='Valid Open SSl Certificate', encryption_certificate_id='Valid Open SSl Certificate ID', 
    expiration_date_time=DateTime(2024, 7, 16, 6, 1, 4, 250816, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), include_resource_data=True, latest_supported_tls_version='v1_2', 
    lifecycle_notification_url='<ngrok_url>/lifecycleurl'
, notification_query_options=None, notification_url='<ngrok_url>/api'
, notification_url_app_id=None, resource='communications/onlineMeetings/getAllTranscripts')


We are trying to get the list of subscription at tenant-level by below code:

response = await graph_client.subscriptions.get()
subscriptions = response.value
print(f"Subscription Count: {len(subscriptions)}")
for subscription in subscriptions:
    print(f"Subscription ID: {subscription.id}, Resource: {subscription.resource}")

But here the subscription counts returns '0' instead of 1.
[ Note: Subscription is not expired. We are trying to retrieve the subscription list before the subscription expiration happens ]
Can you please let know why the subscription count is 0 even when the subscription is created successfully?

Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?


get the list of subscription at tenant-level.

You can use the below code to get the list of subscription at tenant level with count using Azure Python SDK.
Code:
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient


def main():
    client = SubscriptionClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
    )

    response = client.subscriptions.list()
    subscriptions = list(response)
    count = len(subscriptions)
    print(f"Subscription Count: {count}")
    for subscription in subscriptions:
        print(f"Subscription Name: {subscription.display_name}, Subscription ID: {subscription.subscription_id}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

For configuration, store the service principal credentials as environment variables.
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=<your-client-id>
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=<your-client-secret>
AZURE_TENANT_ID=<your-tenant-id>

Output:
Subscription Count: 16
Subscription Name: MSxxxxxxxxing, Subscription ID: 08xxxxxd5bd5860
Subscription Name: AMLxxxxxe R&D, Subscription ID: 0cafx-64cexx324e1xxxxxx
Subscription Name: xxxxxsktop-01, Subscription ID: 54b8xbc7ddf4dxxxxxxxx
Subscription Name: Anxxxxxuction, Subscription ID: dadxxxxxx38fbadb6
Subscription Name: COSxxxxxound, Subscription ID: 3967xxxxxxxedbd4f
Subscription Name: ODxxxxxces, Subscription ID: a471xxxxx19543d4691e
Subscription Name: Azxxxxx CDP ER - Test, Subscription ID: b65b516xxxxa7411275f8
Subscription Name: AML Ixxxxxxxering System, Subscription ID: fxxxxxx207ca0723ed
Subscription Name: xxxxxxxption, Subscription ID: 86f0xxxxx1c74faa4ee
Subscription Name: IDxxxxxting, Subscription ID: baxxxxxda1d6e
Subscription Name: MxModern Mgmt-Imagixxxng00, Subscription ID: 29de2xxx795bd282
Subscription Name: xxxxDev, Subscription ID: 462829xxxxbb
Subscription Name: CSX-WSDxxxxxITHUB, Subscription ID: 3cd019xxxx28765
Subscription Name: Daxxxxxxling, Subscription ID: 602xxxxxxx59f2454106
Subscription Name: CxxxxPP, Subscription ID: 44074xxxxx736a45
Subscription Name: Quanxxxxxructure, Subscription ID: c7xxxxxxx


Reference:
Subscriptions - List - REST API (Azure Subscription) | Microsoft Learn
